# Zombie/trash thread on MacOS with Rosetta

Tags: c++, multithreading, macos, crash

I have a very weird issue with a zombie/garbage thread crashing the process although this thread should have been joined a while ago.

Application written in C++, built for x86_64, runs on MacOS using Rosetta. Googletest runs app multiple times: initializes the engine, performs tests and uninitializes it for every test - no new processes are started - all happens within googletest process. In about one goggletest start of about ten, one of the threads that my application has *not* created during current run crashes with invalid resource access which triggers `SIGABRT` and crashes the complete process.

Threads in the pool are created like this during thread pool construction, done once during application initialization:

```
// threadsNum is a constant, e.g. 8
for (size_t i = 0; i < threadsNum; ++i){
    // this->workers has type std::vector< std::thread > workers;
    workers.emplace_back(
        [this, i]
        {
            workerThreadFunction(i);
        }
    );
}
```

`workerThreadFunction()` sets thread name and enters an infinete loop for doing it's job while checking if it should stop in every iteration:

```
for (;;) {
    // Mutex lock to access this->stop
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(this->queue_mutex);
    if (this->stop) {
        break;
    }
    ...
}
```

During thread pool destruction all threads are joined:

```
for(std::thread &worker: workers) {
    worker.join();
}
```

To sum up:

1. Application starts 8 threads for a specfic task using a thread pool
2. Threads have their names for debugging purposes - e.g. "MyThread 1", "MyThread 2", etc.
3. I have verified that all threads are joined upon thread pool destruction (`threadX.join()` returns)
4. Application shutdown is clean after test iteration execution before the next test with the crash starts
5. In problematic runs with the crash there are more threads present than application has created - one of the threads is present two times (thread name duplicated). Crash dump also shows there are two threads with the same name and one of them has crashed.
6. That duplicated thread has corrupt stack and crashes due to invalid resource access (locking `this->queue_mutex` to be precise)
7. Additional main thread sleep for e.g. 100ms after engine uninitialization does not help - does not look like a timing issue

To me it looks like that thread has survived `join()` somehow and reappeared in the process. But I cannot imagine how could it be possible.

The question is, am I missing something here? Are there any tools to debug this issue besides what I have already done?

Comment: Two cases come in mind. 1. `this` is died, dangling pointer in threads. 2. Memory corrupted by not shown code. Build and run the app with the thread sanitizer. Build and run app with the address sanitizer.

Comment: Yes, `this` is dead for that problematic thread that was never started, which is kind of expected for such a thread. All other threads that were actually started have valid `this` and stacks. This also never happens on intel Macs - the same test suite runs there. Thanks for the hint - I'll try running with sanitizers.

Comment: Thread sanitizer helped indeed! Found a race condition on shutdown.

Comment: It happened... again.